# Switching USB mode from host to device without OTG

Tags: usb, embedded-linux, usb-otg

I want to connect a smartphone with an embedded Linux platform over USB. My application needs the Linux platform first to act as USB host and the smartphone as device. Later I need them to switch their roles and the Linux platform to become the device and the smartphone to become the USB Host. The USB controller on the Linux platform does not support OTG and therefore I need another solution which enables this role switch. Does anyone have an idea how I can switch the roles of both from my application/ in the terminal?

Comment: Which USB controller are you using? Which driver, etc.? Given that you say that it doesn't support OTG, I'd guess that it's a pure host controller, and can't act as a device controller and work as a gadget.

Comment: @Hasturkun, most of the controllers do not support OTG and at the same time can be peripheral or host. People simply do not understand what OTG is and what the difference to DR (dual-role). Note, 99.9% of the switchable controllers are DR, and not OTG.

Comment: Hi @Hasturkun, indeed it's a host controller (TQMLS102xA). Even if the data-sheet states, that USB 2.0 high speed OTG is possible, I think OTG won't work as the ID-Pin is not connected on our platform. That's what I found about our drivers: xHCI HCD (USB 3.0) support and EHCI (USB 2.0) support. 0andriy, do you know, how we can check, if the controller supports dual-role or how to enable it? I searched the buildroot for dual-role but didn't find anything. Apart from that we need to switch the roles at runtime of the application.

Comment: From poking about (and assuming you're using their BSP stuff), it looks like there might be a `dwc3` driver there, which you can force to mode switch by writing one of "host", "device", "otg" into `/sys/kernel/debug/dwc3/mode` (where I'm not sure about `dwc3` as it's taken from the device name, and it might only affect USB 3.0). I can't actually verify any of this, though, and I'm mostly relying on what's in their "zeus" meta-tq release.

Comment: Hi @Hasturkun, thanks for the tip to try it with debugfs. I have no path with **dwc3** but after mounting debugfs I had **/sys/kernel/debug/3100000.usb3/mode**. Checking the current mode with `cat mode` I got `host` as expected. When I try to change the mode with `echo device > mode` the mode doesn't change. Do you have an Idea what could be the reason?